# Show message depending on typed text in textfield

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

Good day! i have this code for UIAlertView that when you press the button it will show a message what ever you typed.

```
- (IBAction)sellClick:(id)sender {

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle: @"Confirmation"
                                                       message: @"Message"
                                                      delegate: self
                                             cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                             otherButtonTitles:@"OK",nil];


        [alert show];
        [alert release];
}
```

now what i want is what if i have 3 or more UITextfields and when i press the button i want to show all the typed text in UItextfield to UIAlertView for example in my 1st text field i typed. "WANT" and 2nd is "LARRY" and 3rd is "PLAY" when i press the button it shows the alert message, "I WANT LARRY to PLAY" , how can i make it like that? thanks!

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far, and what isn't working?

Comment: I haven't done anything because i can't find any solution for this. im just a beginner on coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your text fields are added to the view in XIB then make sure you have your `IBOutlets` connected to your textfields. Such as:

```
@property (weak) IBOutlet UITextField* textField1;
@property (weak) IBOutlet UITextField* textField2;
@property (weak) IBOutlet UITextField* textField3;
```

Then you could simply compose a message:

```
NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"I %@ %@ to %@",self.textField1.text,self.textField2.text,self.textField3.text];

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle: @"Confirmation"
                                                       message: message
                                                      delegate: self
                                             cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                             otherButtonTitles:@"OK",nil];

...
```

Comment: Your comment about outlets is irrelevant to the question and not necessarily true. Maybe the text fields were created in code.

Answer (score 1):

You can create string with your uitextfields like:

```
- (IBAction)sellClick:(id)sender {

        NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"I %@ %@ to %@", textField1.text, textField1.text, textField1.text]
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle: @"Confirmation"
                                                       message: message
                                                      delegate: self
                                             cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                             otherButtonTitles:@"OK",nil];


        [alert show];
        [alert release];
}
```

Hope this help.